# Problem with importing module and NameError: global name 'module' is not defined

Tags: python, namespaces, module

Sorry, if this question has been asked before.  I've looked around for quite a while and I haven't found a solution.

So I've created a class in the file ResourceOpen.py

```
class ResourceOpen():

    import urllib.request

    def __init__(self, source):
            try:
                # Try to open URL
                page = urllib.request.urlopen(source)
                self.text = page.read().decode("utf8")
            except ValueError:
                # Fail? Print error.
                print ("Woops!  Can't find the URL.")
                self.text = ''

    def getText(self):
        return self.text
```

I would like to use this class in another program,youTubeCommentReader.py...

```
import ResourceOpen
import urllib.request

pageToOpen = "http://www.youtube.com"
resource = ResourceOpen.ResourceOpen(pageToOpen)
text = resource.getText()
```

Whenever I try and run youTubeCommentReader, I get the error:

```
Traceback               
    <module>    D:\myPythonProgs\youTubeCommentReader.py
    __init__    D:\myPythonProgs\ResourceOpen.py
NameError: global name 'urllib' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?  Also, I should note that ResourceOpen.py works fine when I access the class within the same file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't import on the class level, just do:

```
import urllib.request

class ResourceOpen():    

    def __init__(self, source):
            try:
                # Try to open URL
                page = urllib.request.urlopen(source)
                self.text = page.read().decode("utf8")
            except ValueError:
                # Fail? Print error.
                print ("Woops!  Can't find the URL.")
                self.text = ''

    def getText(self):
        return self.text
```

In the other script:

```
import ResourceOpen
s = ResourceOpen.ResourceOpen('http://google.com')
print(s.getText())
```

In your case the module is imported just fine, but only added to the classes namespace. You always want imports on the global level.

Comment: I have tried that, and it still gives me the same error.  It's like the import statement within ResourceOpen is ignored whenever I try and import it into another program.  When I use the ResourceOpen class within the same file, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your original code is that `urllib.request` ends up being a class attribute, so you would have to say `self.urllib.request.urlopen(...)` in your `__init__`.  `import`'s are much better off at the module level.